# flutter_inappwebview - How to update URL?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I would like to know how I can update my URL with the `flutter_inappwebview` package.

Here is my code:

```
InAppWebView(
  initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
    data: videoName,
  ),
```

The `videoName` variable is updated using `setState`. However, InAppWebView does not display the new URL.

How can I update `videoName` using `setState`?

Comment: I think you need to create a InAppWebViewController and pass to the InAppWebView, then use loadUrl from the controller. See: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/in-app-webview-controller-methods/

Comment: @JorgeVieira Thank you. Your recommendation was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 page :1) videopage 2)webviewpage

1. video page so :

From the video page pass the url with parameter in webviewpage .

Example:

In Video View Page :

Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute -> (builder)=> WevViewPage(url);

In web view Page :

WebViewPage extents stateless ...

String url;

WebViewPage(this.url);
//here is the constructor

now show

```
InAppWebView(
  initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
    data: url,
  ),
```